# Looking for React oriented graph renderer with custom nodes and auto positioning

Tags: reactjs, graph

I have a graph data structure which can almost be called a tree except for the fact that some nodes point to other branches.
For example: [image]

I am looking for a React package that could render this on screen and most of them don't do it as I would like.

I need to be able to create a custom node appearance, for example: a rectangle with an icon inside, instead of the regular circle.

A big plus would be for the package to be able to position the nodes automatically so that it would look something like the illustration above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: such questions are not well received on SO though are very popular

Comment: So where should I ask questions of this sort?

Comment: there is a discord server all things about react: https://www.reactiflux.com/, click join reactiflux